# Why does my mesh change when i render it?

Tags: animation, displacement

I'v created an animation with a simple displace modifier and textures and it looks just fine in rendered view, but as soon as I hit "render" it deforms to this low poly mess. What am I doing wrong?

[image: picture with a screenshot of the original on the left and the problematic result on the right]

Comment: Recommend having modifier settings in screenshot, and / or upload a [demo file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Are your render subsurf levels different from the viewport levels?

Answer (score 4):

[Modifiers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) can be disabled in viewport and/or render. The subsurf and multires modifiers also have different settings for render and viewport.

The camera icon controls the render view and the eye icon controls the viewport.

[image: a subsurf modifier not visible in render]